# How to close Apex Modal page from iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, oracle-apex

I have an Apex 19.2 page. Inside the page there is an iframe from another page of the same application.

Once some process are successful inside the iFrame, I would like to allow the user to close the modal page by clicking a button inside the iFrame.

I tried a dynamic action with Close/Cancel dialog but it's not working.

Has anyone an idea how to do that please ?

Thanks,
cheers,

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

From the iFrame :

```
parent.apex.navigation.dialog.close(true)
```